# replace varying number of spaces in file with single space

Tags: bash, sed

I have a list of files that have columns separated by varying number of spaces. HOw can I sed or similar this so that each column is separated by a single space or tab?

I tried:

```
 sed 's/ \+ /\t/g' file > tmp
 sed "s/\ /\t/g" tmp > file
```

but R complained

```
line 526 did not have 11 elements
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [tr](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tr-invocation.html)

```
tr -s < fileName
```

or [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html)

```
sed -e 's/ \+/ /g' fileName
```

Inline sed

```
sed -i.bak -e 's/ \+/ /g' fileName
```

Comment: I didn't have `-s` option in `tr` command, my tr version is `tr (GNU coreutils) 8.4` running on `centOS`, can you share your `tr` version?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
sed 's/ \{1,\}/\t/g' file > tmp
```

This takes one or more spaces and converts to the string in the second part of the expression ('\t' here).

Comment: + 1 Welcome to the site. you could also specify "-i" for in place

Comment: Thanks! The -i option is useful, but be careful to supply the suffix required to create a backup. Easy to overwrite a single copy with -i alone.

Answer (score 0):

Let say you have the file named "raw_file" that have the text below inside

```
COLUMN1            COLUMN2         COLUMN3     COLUMN4
I      am   a boy
Hello word

I            see you
I am 5 years
How are    you?
```

You can use the command:

```
sed 's/ \{1,\}/ /g' '/root/Desktop/raw_file' |column -s ' ' -t > '/root/Desktop/my_new_file'
```

**RESULTS WHEN OUTPUT TO A NEW FILE CALLED "my_new_file"**

```
COLUMN1  COLUMN2  COLUMN3  COLUMN4
I        am       a        boy
Hello    word
I        see      you
I        am       5        years
```

**RESULTS WHEN OUTPUT TO THE TERMINAL**

Command used:

```
sed 's/ \{1,\}/ /g' '/root/Desktop/raw_file' |column -s ' ' -t 2>  /dev/null
```

Results:

```
COLUMN1  COLUMN2  COLUMN3  COLUMN4
I        am       a        boy
Hello    word
I        see      you
I        am       5        years
```

**NOTE:** Each column is separated by two spaces.

Answer (score 0):

awk will take care of whitespace directly and easily

```
awk '$1=$1' infile     # convert to single space

or

awk '$1=$1' OFS="\t" infile     # convert to single tab
```

If you have to use SED, The character class `\s` will match the whitespace characters `tab` and `space`

so your sed code can be fixed as

```
sed 's/\s\{1,\}/ /g' infile

or

sed 's/\s\{1,\}/\t/g' infile
```

if your sed support `-r` option,

```
sed -r 's/\s+/ /g' infile

or

sed -r 's/\s+/\t/g' infile
```